# Does sum of sequence $\sum \frac{1}{n (1+\frac{1}{2}+ \dots + \frac{1}{n})}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

A direct proof is hard, and I tried to develop the following equivalence:

The convergence of $\sum \frac{x_n}{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}$ is the same as $\sum x_n$, but I still don't know how to prove it

Comment: $1+1/2+..1/n$ diverges

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Are you saying the sum converges, or the terms of the sequence converge?

Comment: This is an example of the following rule:  Let $a_n$ be the positive terms of a series whose partial sums $S_n$ diverge.  Then the partial sums of the series whose terms are $a_n/S_n$ also diverge.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure but I'd say,

No. Considering that $$\sum_{k=1}^{t}\frac{1}{k} $$ asympotomically tends to $\ln n$, and considering that $$\sum_{k=1}^{t}\frac{1}{k \ln k}$$ Diverges via integral test, I think it diverges.

Comment: Think you should be summing over $k$ in your second sum, but you're otherwise on the money. The inequality $H_n<\log(n+1)$ can be used to tighten up the formalism a little, but the idea is very much correct.

Answer (score 3):

No: it is a series with positive terms, so we can proceed by *equivalence*. $$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+ \dots + \dfrac{1}{n}\sim_\infty\log n\enspace\text{hence}\quad
\frac{1}{n (1+\dfrac{1}{2}+ \dots + \dfrac{1}{n})}\sim_\infty\frac1{n\log n},$$
which is a divergent *Bertrand's series* .